# Change QT layout background

Tags: c++, css, qt, background-image

Since `QVBoxLayout` has no a `setStylesheet` method, I thought this would made the trick:

```
QWidget *window = new QWidget(this);
window->setStyleSheet("background-image:url(:/images/sky.jpg);font-size:18px;");
QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout(window);
layout->addWidget(widg1);
layout->addWidget(widg2);
setLayout(layout);
```

Sadly, only a small rectangle of background image appears, not covering entire window. How could I do it?

Comment: I know it has been a long while, but if you can post a screenshot of how your application looks like it would be very useful. I made a small example based on your code and it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set stylesheet to the central widget of your main window. In the example you can put `window` into some other layout.